# Connecting to Stomp over WebSockets implemented using Spring 4 from Java client

Tags: tomcat, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I received a Web application, implemented with Spring using STOMP over WebSockets Messaging, similar to what's described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) (with RabbitMQ at the backend). It runs on Tomcat, and I can connect to the application using regular URLs (e.g. `http://host/server/`). I was also given a demo client - a JSPX page, which uses Modernizr WebSockets and SockJS. The connection code in the demo client looks like this:

```
if (Modernizr.websockets) {
    socket = new WebSocket('ws://host/server/endpointx');
}
else {
    socket = new SockJS('/server/endpointy');
}

stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect(headers, function(frame) { ... });
....
```

Demo client works fine (when I load JSPX page in the browser, I can connect to the server). But my goal is to connect to the same server using some Java STOMP library. Problem is, the libraries I tried, require **host** and **port** as connection parameters: For example with [ActiveMQ Stomp library](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html):

```
StompConnection connection = new StompConnection();
connection.open("host", port);
connection.connect(new HashMap<String, String>());
```

If I specify `port` as `61613`, connection succeeds, but I hit RabbitMQ directly, not my server (this is not what I want). If I specify `8080` (or `80`), on connection I get an error

> java.io.EOFException
>       at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.unmarshal(StompWireFormat.java:137)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection.receive(StompConnection.java:77)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection.receive(StompConnection.java:68)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection.connect(StompConnection.java:139)
>       at ....stomp.impl.activemq.ActiveMQStompDriver.connect(ActiveMQStompDriver.java:39)
>       ... 25 more

and trace shows that this is because `CONNECT` frame never receives an expected `CONNECTED` frame (in fact, it doesn't receive anything back).

So I'm puzzled: am I using a wrong port? or dealing with some library incompatibility? or do I need to somehow indicate Tomcat that I want to [upgrade HTTP connection to WebSockets](http://enterprisewebbook.com/ch8_websockets.html)?

If the above question is difficult to answer, then this one is equally useful: how do I connect to Spring application with STOMP over WebSockets messaging channel running on Tomcat using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have posted an answer when I found it.
In order to implement Java client, connecting to Tomcat, and not to RabbitMQ directly, the Java client should not only implement STOMP Over WebSockets, but also [an opening handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3):

> The opening handshake is intended to be compatible with HTTP-based
> server-side software and intermediaries, so that a single port can be
> used by both HTTP clients talking to that server and WebSocket
> clients talking to that server.  To this end, the WebSocket client's
> handshake is an HTTP Upgrade request

The libraries I tried to use were simply missing this capability. They tried to directly perform WebSocket connection without the handshake.

So to answer my own questions:

- Library must support opening handshake
- For host and port you need to specify Tomcat's host (of not the same as RabbitMQ), and **web port (e.g. 8080), not RabbitMQ port**

I ended up using [Spring WebSocket library](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/), which allows all that quite easily. Here's the simplest setup:

```
taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
taskScheduler.setPoolSize(N); // N = number of threads
taskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();

stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(new StandardWebSocketClient());
stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter()); 

WebSocketHttpHeaders handshakeHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders(); // you can add additional headers here for Tomcat

// Here's the main piece other libraries were missing:
// The following request will perform both, handshake and connection
// hence it gets both sets of headers (for Tomcat and for Stomp)
ListenableFuture<StompSession> future = stompClient.connect(
            url,
            handshakeHeaders,
            new StompHeaders(),
            new CustomStompSessionHandlerAdapter(this)); // called from class that also was implementing CustomStompSessionHandlerAdapter, but this could be separate class as well.
```

Also see [WebSocket Support section in Spring reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html)